# How to call function on submit in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to call to function onsubmit in codeigniter.
One for submit and one for Access some id.

I like to know that how to call two function on submit, also i need to know how to submit form by ajax if i have true condition.

My ajax controller:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    add = function (){

    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",              
                url: ajax_url_store,       
                data: {action: 'store', views: JSON.stringify(thsirtDesigner.getProduct()) },

                success: function(data) {
                     if(parseInt(data) > 0) {
                        // i need to submit my form here...

                         }

                },
                error: function() {
                    //alert('some error has occured...');
                },
                start: function() {
                    //alert('ajax has been started...');    
                }
            });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery you can use :

```
$("#formId").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //your code
});
```

And in javascript

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return yourfunction()">
</function>

function yourfunction()
{
  //your code
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether you are using codeigniter or normal php simply use Ajax, [Check this link](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$('input#submitbuttonid').click( function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'url to post data',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('form#formid').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
               ...your data logic comes here
             }
});
});
```

And simple Javascript ,

```
$('form#formid').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle you form submission by jquery. to do this you can use one of jquery plugin for this purpose. i refer [JqueryForm plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to you.

by this plugin you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",              
   url: ajax_url_store,       
   data: {action: 'store', views: JSON.stringify(thsirtDesigner.getProduct()) },

        success: function(data) {
            if(parseInt(data) > 0) {
                  var options = { 
                     target:        '#message_box_id',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 

                     url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
                     type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
                    dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
                    clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
                    resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

                }; 

               // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
               $('#your_form_id').ajaxForm(options);

            }

            },
            error: function() {
                //alert('some error has occured...');
            },
          start: function() {
         //alert('ajax has been started...');    
    }
});
```

i don't know what exactly you want to do but maybe you can use before submit feature of this plugin to solve you issue. for example you can try this way

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output1',
        beforeSubmit:  your_ajax_function,
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 


        url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
        type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
        clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
    }; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    $('#your_form_id').ajaxForm(options); 

    your_ajax_function = function(){
        $.ajax({
            // your ajax body
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//stop the form from submitting you can select form by adding a class or id
$('form').submit(function(e){e.preventDefault});

//when a button with id submit is clicked
//fire ajax
$('button#submit').on('click',function(){
  // your ajax code
});
```